# Compare WSO2 Identity Server and SCIM

Tags: security, authentication, wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I want to know which one is better in terms of security features: WSO2 Identity Server or SCIM. I have read both their documentations and RFCs (for SCIM), but I cannot figure out which one would be a better option to use to provide security for a website which is going to handle huge user load. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> WSO2 Identity Server or SCIM

IMHO you are mixing apples and oranges

[WSO2 Identity Server](https://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management) (WSO2 IS) is an identity server (a product) intended to authenticate and authorize clients (users or systems). WSO2 IS supports multiple autentication protocols (SAML, OAuth, ..).

[SCIM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644) is a defined protocol (set of messages and formats) how to exchange identity information (users, groups, roles) between systems.

WSO2 IS can use SCIM protocol to exchange users with other system - create users in external applications or let external applications create users in WSO2 IS' userstore.

> better option to use to provide security for a website which is going to handle huge user load

WSO2 IS is an out-of-box product ready to be used. The product is involved only during authentication/authorization, so the load in the identity server is not really dependend on the application load (unless the application is not requesting XACML authorization for everything)